# How to add footer for active admin which should contain text and image within div?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class Footer < Component

      def build
        super :id => "footer"                                                    
        super :style => "text-align: left;"        

       div do 
         h5 "Powered by"
         image_tag ("/images/myridz_logo.png")
       end
     end
   end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
div do 
  h5 "Powered by"
  img src: "/images/myridz_logo.png", id: 'abc'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably customise the `activeadmin` factories for this purpose. You will find [this tutorial](http://reverbhq.com/blog/2012/08/building-web-apps-with-activeadmin/) helpful.